# How to properly create multiple knowledge bases into qnamaker.ai and then connect with Luis.ai

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

When I initially used the deployment scripts and deployed my Virtual Assistant chat Bot,and it created some default knowledge bases into my Qnmaker.ai. all worked fine.

Now I added another new set of faq knowledge base into my Qnmaker.ai,updated the cognitivemodels.json in my solution with the new knowledgebase id,endpointkey etc. what is the next steps in this so that it can dynamically identify and generate the luis intents along with required utterances etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `update_cognitive_models.ps1` and also update the Dialogs/MainDialog.cs file to include the corresponding Dispatch intent for your new QnA source as described in steps 3 and 4 in the [documentation here](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/tutorials/csharp/customize-assistant/4_edit_your_cognitive_models/).

Comment: Make sure to include -RemoteToLocal option in update_cognitive_models.ps1.  This will update dispatch based on qnamaker.ai knowledgebases and not the last created local copies.

Comment: the link is broken